# Can I prevent save target as using HttpHandler?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, download, httphandler

I would like to proccess all download requests from anywhere like save target as or clicking on file in my sharepoint website.
I have implemented my own httphandler but save target as is ignoring my handler.
First of all, Can I prevent file download using handler or not? My target is sharepoint document library. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You'll want to implement an IHttpModule. A single handler gets called during the request lifetime after all the HttpModules have ran.

[Here's a great site that shows the lifetime of a request](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers)
[And here's the less-readable Microsoft version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985)